# ArcGIS Pro Python install causing issues with importing packages

Tags: arcgis-pro, windows, python-3

I've looked at several posts and articles and I can't seem to find a solution to this. I need to use jenkspy for a specific task but my Python 3x was installed with a software called ArcGIS Pro that designates the default Python environment "Read Only" meaning that packages not installed with it must be installed in a virtual environment.

So, I opened command line and ran:

```
py -m venv env
py -m pip install jenkspy --user
```

If I continue to run python from command window I can import jenkspy no problem. However, when I attempt to import it in iPython or load it into pythonWin as a script I get:

```
import jenkspy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jenkspy'
```

So I go back to command window and run python to locate path for jenkspy:

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

which returns:

```
['', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64', 'C:\\Users\\johnsmith\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I navigate to the native idle.py file in this environment and import jenkspy. No problem. I print sys.path from the idle console. Same result as in command line.

I then go back to iPython and run:

```
import sys
paths = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64', 'C:\\Users\\johnsmith\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib\\site-packages']

for p in paths:
    sys.path.append(p)
```

and then:

```
import jenkspy
```

And I get this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-88ab181dc114> in <module>
----> 1 import jenkspy

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jenkspy\__init__.py in <module>
      3 __version__ = "0.1.5"
      4 
----> 5 from .core import jenks_breaks
      6 
      7 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jenkspy\core.py in <module>
      7     from math import isinf, isnan
      8     isfinite = lambda x: not isinf(x) and not isnan(x)
----> 9 from . import jenks
     10 try:
     11     import numpy as np

ImportError: cannot import name 'jenks'
```

Tried to do conda install. Works fine in iPython if I open the venv jupyter notebook. Still, not seeing how this will work in a stand alone script which I need it to do because this will be a batch job run daily.

from anaconda prompt these are available envs:

```
base                  *  C:\Users\reguser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2
agolupdate               C:\Users\reguser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\agolupdate
```

This is from `print (sys.path)` in ArcGIS Pro python window:

```
C:\\Users\\adm.user\\AppData\\Local\\ESRI\\conda\\envs\\arcgispro-py3-clone2
```

What do I need to do in order to get jenkspy or other post Python installation packages/modules to be imported using stand alone scripts and or/iPython?

Comment: ArcGIS Pro uses conda, so don't use pipenv, use conda to create read-write envs - https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/what-is-conda.htm

Comment: not that easy. I have to profiles on the machine. Pro runs on an adm account but is accessed through a regular user profile session on the workstation while ran as the adm user. So, the venv with conda goes to the goes to the reg account and then arcpro can't see it. When I sign on the workstation as adm I can't get to anaconda prompt to run conda installs.

Comment: Our corporate setup is similar.  We just need to either use the full path to conda (C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Bin\Python\Scripts\conda) or add that Scripts path to our `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I tried adding as sys path to the cloned env using sys.path.append but it didn't work.